# Delay CSS in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, settimeout, delay

I have this div I want to hide (`display:none`) after it fades out, so I enter this:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:"0"},{duration:200});
    $(this).delay(200).css('display','none');
});
```

And I suddenly remember that delay()s don't work for css.  I used to have a little setTimeout fix for this lying around but can't find it anywhere so I tried random stuff like this:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:"0"},{duration:200});
});
$('.element').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).css('display','none');
    },200);
});
```

Still doesn't work.  Can someone help me out here please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's .animate() has a callback feature, you can send an anonymous function to be executed once the animation is done:

```
$(this).animate({opacity:"0"},{duration:200}, function(){
   $(this).css('display','none');
});
```

source: [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [animate callback function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), that function will initualise when animation complete.

Structure is like this = .animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )

Example:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({opacity:"0"},200,function() {//use callback here
       $(this).css('display','none');
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably no need to delay the css anymore. I assume this was just so that its ran after the `animate`

Answer (score 1):

A more Elegant way of doing it is by specifying a callBack function to run after the animation.

Eg:

```
$(this).animate({opacity:"0"},200,function(){

     $(this).css('display','none');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.element').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete. do something here if you want
 });
```